# How to change duration of timeout after too many incorrect password attempts in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, passwords, login-screen, windows-10-pro

Using Windows 10 Pro, I authenticate in the login screen with my password.

It often happens that I mistype my password multiple times and at a certain point the password prompt is delayed for a minute preventing me from using my PC.

I know that the timeout is a security feature, yet in the setup of my own home and due to my innate inability to properly type: How do I decrease the timeout after too many incorrect password attempts?

---

Edition: Windows 10 Pro
Version: 20H2
OS build: 19042.746

Comment: This is handled by a group policy.  Have you tried setting that group policy.  I assume you have done the proper amount of research to identify that policy and your wondering why it doesn’t work.

Comment: @Ramhound Group Policy requires Windows 10 Pro or higher.

Comment: Hence the reason I asked if the author was stuck and I have no reason to believe they are NOT running Windows 10 Professional but also easily overcome by using **net accounts /lockoutduration:Number** in an elevated command prompt

Comment: @Ramhound It's Windows 10 Pro

Comment: @LPChip It's Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 1):

This duration is determined by the policy named **Account Lockout Policy**
found in the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) at
`Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies\Account Lockout Policy`.

Unfortunately, this policy is described in Microsoft's `gpedit` as:

> This security setting determines the **number of minutes** a locked-out account remains locked out before automatically becoming unlocked. The available range is from 0 minutes through 99,999 minutes. **If you set the account lockout duration to 0, the account will be locked out until an administrator explicitly unlocks it**.

This means that your timeout of one minute is already the minimum setting that
is possible.

I think that the only real solution is to change your password to a
simpler one. If this is your home computer, the risk is not large.

See the article
[How to Change Password of Local Account or Microsoft Account in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5239-change-account-password-windows-10-a.html).

---

Another useful setting:

**Account lockout threshold**

> This security setting determines the number of failed logon attempts that causes a user account to be locked out. A locked-out account cannot be used until it is reset by an administrator or until the lockout duration for the account has expired. You can set a value between 0 and 999 failed logon attempts. If you set the value to 0, the account will never be locked out.

Comment: Editing GPO requires Windows 10 Pro or higher. Windows 10 Home users will not be able to change this.

Comment: @LPChip: [How to enable gpedit.msc (Group Policy) on Windows 10 Home devices](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/01/07/how-to-enable-gpedit-msc-group-policy-on-windows-10-home-devices/).

Comment: Just wondering: Is it possible to increase the amount of tries before the duration triggers instead?

Comment: @k0pernikus - Your question does not make sense care to explain?  However, strictly speaking, that would be it's own question.  However, you are expected to do adequate research before asking a question.

Comment: @k0pernikus: I added it to my answer.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (tick the V sign).

Comment: @harrymc I will once I manage to try it out :)